# Node.js SFTP client

Tags: javascript, client, node.js, sftp

I want to access sftp servers through a node.js app. Do you know a library for this? Or have you an idea how I could realize this?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be SSH2(https://www.npmjs.org/package/ssh2) library will help you

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a library already written for this, but you could perhaps use the sftp client via a [child process](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/child_processes.html).

Comment: Ok I'll try it with that. Thanks!