# SSH client for Node.js

Tags: javascript, ssh, node.js

Is there a SSH client for node.js I could use to communicate with a server?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> An SSH2 client module written in pure JavaScript for node.js

https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2

Also checkout this wrapper for it

https://github.com/mikeal/sequest

Comment: It really works.
I can login via ssh to my Cisco router and execute commands.

Comment: What do you think of this wrapper https://github.com/steelbrain/node-ssh

Answer (score 17):

Node.js child processes won't do if you need to use a password for login, because OpenSSH client does not read the password from stdin, but from a pseudo terminal.

You can work around this by using [pty.js](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/):

```
var pty = require("pty.js");
var term = pty.spawn("ssh", ["username@localhost", "whoami"]);

term.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log("Incoming: " + data.toString());
});

// Wait a sec before sending the password. For proper implementation 
// you should wait for the password prompt.
setTimeout(function(){
  term.write("mypassword\n");
}, 1000);
```

This being said, you should always use SSH key pairs for this if possible.

Answer (score 12):

Here are two other options:

- [NodeSSH client](https://github.com/VanCoding/NodeSSH)
- [node-control](https://github.com/tsmith/node-control)

The client is pretty solid and basic for general use.  Node-control is more suited for parallel, async control over many machines (i.e. sys-admin work).

Comment: Have you noticed that my Nickname is a part of the URL? ^^ The client code is mine.

Comment: @VanCoding lol haha. Always funny when someone answers with something you wrote.

Comment: @VanCoding - What was the purpose of your question if you've written this already?

Answer (score 3):

Much like with sftp in [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174626/node-js-sftp-client), you could perhaps use the ssh client via a [child process](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/child_processes.html).

Comment: Ok I'll try it with that. Thanks!

Comment: Scraping command line tools works, but is a very fragile interface. An actual NPM module would be much more reliable.