Persistently run SSH commands in child_process
I am trying to start an remote ssh session to a linux machine using NodeJS. My requirements is to run multiple shell commands in the same ssh session one after another. Currently I am using simple-ssh npm package which works but my requirements says to not rely on third party tools / packages. Instead, I am suggested to use child_process for the remote ssh session.
Following is the example using simple-ssh package:
var SSH = require("simple-ssh")

var ssh = new SSH({
    host: 'remote_host',
    user: 'username',
    pass: 'password'
});

ssh.exec('pwd', {
        out: console.log.bind(console)
    })
    .exec('ls', {
        out: console.log.bind(console)
    })
    .exec('date', {
        out: console.log.bind(console)
    })
    .start();

Following is the one I tried with child_process:
  const { spawn } = require('child_process');
  const child1 = spawn('sshpass', ['-p', 'password', 'ssh', '-T', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', `'username'@'remote_host'`]);
       
   child1.stdin.write('password\n');

   child1.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
       console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
   });
   child1.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
       console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
   });
   child1.on('close', (code) => {
       console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
   });


   const child2 = spawn('sshpass', ['-p', 'password', 'ssh', '-T', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', `'username'@'remote_host'`]);
       
   child2.stdin.write('password\n');

   child2.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
       console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
   });
   child2.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
       console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
   });
   child2.on('close', (code) => {
       console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
   });
  
   const child3 = spawn('sshpass', ['-p', 'password', 'ssh', '-T', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', `'username'@'remote_host'`]);
       
   child3.stdin.write('password\n');

   child3.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
       console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
   });
   child3.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
       console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
   });
   child3.on('close', (code) => {
       console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
   });

Also, if I run the commands in sequence, and then print the output, I get a single output for all commands (Which I don't want):
    const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    const child = spawn('sshpass', ['-p', 'password', 'ssh', '-T', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', `'username'@'remote_host'`]);
       
    child.stdin.write('pwd\n');

    child.stdin.write('ls -al\n');
        
    child.stdin.write('date\n');
        
    child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    child.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });


My question is how can I chain the three ssh commands with child_process spawn in a persistent session and run the commands asynchronously one after another?

Set 'shell' option to be 'true' to runs command inside of a shell which by default is 'false'. Also you can check the node js child process spawn command documentation
const ssh = spawn(
  "sshpass",
  [
    "-p",
    password,
    "ssh",
    "-T",
    "-o",
    "StrictHostKeyChecking=no",
    `${username}@${host}`,
  ],
  { shell: true }
);


Note: this is not perfect, and could have problem with large outputs e.g. file transfer or similar due to nodes stream/buffer handling stuff. But it should do the job for most scenarios e.g. restarting a service or exec some commands.
Another thing i want to point out is, that i could not get it working with password authentication. Currently this only works with public key authentication.
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const { EOL } = require("os");

(async () => {

    const queue = [];
    let ssh = null;


    function sleep(n) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, n)
        });
    }


    function init() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            // could not get it working with password
            // use public key instead
            let child = ssh = spawn("ssh", ["marc@localhost"]);
            
            let message = (data) => {

                    // for feedback only
                    // the cmd response is returned from the send() function bewlow
                    console.log(`stdout/stderr > ${data}`);

                    if(queue.length === 0 ){

                        // init response
                        // motd/unread mails etc.
                        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);

                    }else{

                        // pop resolve from command queue 
                        // return value should command response
                        // NOTE: "data" event could be fired more than once for larget outputs
                        // -> this would break this queue handling!
                        let done = queue.pop();
                        done(data);

                    }                   
            };

            child.once("spawn", () => {

                console.log("ssh child command spawend");

                // we do not care if writen to stdout or stderr
                // handle both streams the same way
                // if a command fails e.g. like the `cat /etc/groups` below
                // a error messsage is writen to stderr, not stdout.
                child.stderr.on("data", message);
                child.stdout.on("data", message);                

            });

        });
    }


    function close(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            ssh.once("exit", (code) => {
                if(code === 0){
                    resolve();
                }else{
                    reject(code)
                }
            });

            ssh.stdin.write(`exit${EOL}`);

        });
    }


    function send(cmd) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            ssh.stdin.write(`${cmd}${EOL}`, (err) => {
                if (err) {

                    reject(err);

                } else {

                    console.log(`# cmd "${cmd}" writen & queued - waiting for response`);
                    queue.unshift(resolve);

                }
            });
        });
    }


    await init();
    await sleep(1000);
    await send("uptime")
    await sleep(1000);
    await send("cat /etc/groups"); // fails, becuase /etc/groups does not exists
    await sleep(1000);
    await send("cat /etc/group");
    await sleep(1000);
    await close();

})();

The program spawns a new child ssh child process and wraps around that stdin/stdout streams helper functions, like "send" which sends the command via ssh to your server.
Your main problem was that you did not wait for a response from the ssh child process before your send/piped the next command into it.
I solved this with a (very, very, very) simple "queue" system.
Again, this code is not "perfect", and was quickly put together. Use it with caution!
For the password authentication i searched around and found a couple of similar questions here, but non of them worked for me. (E.g. -tt option for the ssh command).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292887/5781499
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7122115/5781499

The ssh2 npm package (on which simple-ssh relies) implements the ssh protocol in js and uses a network socket to transfer commands. Its not just a wrapper around the ssh command. I though i could copy that "login/password solution"  from there.
