# Javascript / Node.js based equivalent of Fabric?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, fabric

I love how [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/) makes dealing with deployments to multiple servers easy (with proper support for SSH etc).  However, since ours is s node.js based project, it would be great if we could do this in Javascript rather than Python.

What is the closest node.js/Javascript equivalent of Fabric? (If there is one!)

Comment: Why not just use Fabric for your deploys? IME it works quite nicely for all sorts of deploys, not just Python.

Comment: Yes I probably will, but since will prob put node.js on the build/deploy server anyway because of Uglify.JS I wanted to check I'm not ignoring an obvious route.

Answer (score 14):

I wrote [Flightplan](https://github.com/pstadler/flightplan), a node.js library which does exactly what you're asking for. It basically let's you run sequences of shell commands against your localhost and different sets of remote hosts.

Comment: This looks great, thanks.  We're pretty dug in with Fabric now, but I'll definitely check it out as it would be nice to eliminate multiple languages.

Comment: @UpTheCreek please let me know if you have any questions or suggestions.

Comment: Love the API, but it doesn't seem to support user input (eg. a sudo password, or ssh key password) like Fabric does. Is it just missing from the docs, or is it really not supported?

Comment: @BenDowling Flightplan 0.6.0 adds great support for user input and keyboard authentication.

Answer (score 4):

Fabric is basically a high-level ssh client. Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180981/ssh-client-for-node-js) list several Javascript ssh clients:

1. [SSH2 client](http://github.com/mscdex/ssh2)
2. [NodeSSH](https://github.com/VanCoding/NodeSSH)
3. [node-control](https://github.com/tsmith/node-control)